# jQuery Mb slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm new to jQuery mb slider. I downloaded the zip file had a trial run, everything is working fine. But I need to disable the sliding functionality in jQuery mb slider. How to do that?

Demo : http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.valueSlider/demo/demo.html

Documentation : https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.valueSlider/wiki

I want to prevent the sliding. Please help

Comment: Please indicate exactly which utility you are using called "mb slider" (e.g. a link to the site would help) and add code to your question indicating what you've tried that we can inspect to help you out.  Unfortunately without your code we have no idea what is or isn't working.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a "disable" built in to the plugin, just contact the author I'm sure he'd love to either A) walk you through it, B) build the feature into his plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your question and I decided it'd be fun to find a solution (if possible in 15 minutes or less).

As a result I came up with this ==> [mb slider fork](https://github.com/Likwidt/jquery.mb.valueSlider)

Now if you call `$(yourSelector).disableSlider();` after initialization it should freeze your slider

If you call `$(yourSelector).enable slider();` you can get the functionality back

The main changes are in the inc directory and the demo.html